# SSRS: "Contains an error: [BC302205] End of statement expected."

Tags: reporting-services, replace, expression, reporting

I have created a nested replace expression which will change the string in the field based on the current value. I almost have it working, however I am unsure what I need to add in to end the statement. Can anyone help?

```
 =Replace(
Replace(
REPLACE (Fields!DeviceType.Value, "1", "Desktop / Laptop / Server"),
"2", "Server"),
"3", "Printer"),
"4", "Firewall"),
"5", "Managed Switch"),
"6", "Switch"),
"7", "Access Point Controller"),
"8", "Access Point"),
"9", "Desk Phone"),
"10", "Modem"),
"11", "Mobile Phone"),
"12", "DVR"),
"13", "Camera"),
"14", "NAS / SAN"),
"15", "PBX"),
"16", "UPS"),
"17", "Router"),
"18", "Monitor"),
"19", "Docking Station")
```

Comment: Your image link is broken but you should copy/paste the expression text into your question. This makes it easier for others to amend/test.

Comment: @nyccroce
Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You should edit your question now, to add missing details, see Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Feel free to drop me a comment.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added the expression.

Comment: Does your DeviceType field only contain the number or does it also contain other text?

Comment: Just the number. I want it to show the text for the corresponding number to make it easier to understand which device type the asset is when viewing the report. (hope that makes sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `REPLACE` function replaces one piece of text with another within a string so  `=REPLACE("Mobile Phone", "Mobile", "Cell")` would return "Cell Phone". In your case the REPLACE function is not what you need.

Ideally you would have a database table to join to and get the descriptions from there but I'll assume you can't do this for whatever reason.

Therefore what you need is the SWITCH function.

```
=SWITCH (
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "1", "Desktop / Laptop / Server",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "2", "Server",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "3", "Printer",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "4", "Firewall",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "5", "Managed Switch",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "6", "Switch",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "7", "Access Point Controller",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "8", "Access Point",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "9", "Desk Phone",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "10", "Modem",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "11", "Mobile Phone",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "12", "DVR",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "13", "Camera",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "14", "NAS / SAN",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "15", "PBX",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "16", "UPS",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "17", "Router",
    Fields!DeviceType.Value = "18", "Monitor",
    True, "Unknown Device Type")
```

The final expression acts like an `ELSE` in case there is some data you have not covered in your expression.

If this does not work, check that there are no leading/trailing spaces. If there are then you will need to use TRIM (`TRIM(Fields!DeviceType.Value) = ...`)

Also check that the field is text, if it's actually numeric, remove the quotes from around the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If your expression looks good and you are still spinning your wheels on this error, I recommend checking other expressions on the object referenced in the error message, or remove your expression completely and try and save.

I was receiving the same error on a visibility expression that looked clean. The problem turned out to be an extra end paren ")" but the frustration came because the error message was saying it was the tablix visibility expression which I triple checked and everything was fine, it turned out to be a row visibility expression.